# How can I vectorize this Nested for loop

Tags: matlab, performance

I'm trying to vectorize the inner loop but I'm not being able to.

```
for i = 1:NTS          
    U(1) = 0;
    V(1) = 0;
    U(end)=1;
    V(end)=1;

    for j = 2:NAS-1
        U(j) = (b(j) * U(j-1) + a(j) * UOld(j) + c(j) * UOld(j+1)) / gamma(j);
         V(NAS-j+1) = (b(NAS-j+1) * VOld(NAS-j+1-1) + a(NAS-j+1) * VOld(NAS-j+1) + c(NAS-j+1) * V(NAS-j+1+1)) / gamma(NAS-j+1);
    end
end
```

I've tried the following code but I get a wrong result, can someone please help me out if that?

```
U(2:NAS-1) = ((b(2:NAS-1) .* U(1:NAS-2) + a(2:NAS-1) .* UOld(2:NAS-1) + c(2:NAS-1) .* UOld(3:NAS)) ./ gamma(2:NAS-1));
V(NAS-1:-1:2) = ((b(NAS-1:-1:2) .* VOld(NAS-2:-1:1) + a(NAS-1:-1:2) .* VOld(NAS-1:-1:2) + c(NAS-1:-1:2) .* V(NAS:-1:3)) ./ gamma(NAS-1:-1:2));
```

this is the whole code as requested for the minimal verifiable thing. Thanks

```
    clc
    clear

    NTS=1;
    NAS=10;

    U=rand(1,10)*100;
    V=U;

    UU=zeros(1,10);
    VV=zeros(1,10);

    Gamma=ones(1,100)*(1-10.05);
    a=ones(1,10)*(1-0.05);
    b=ones(1,10)*(1-0.15);
    c=ones(1,10)*(1-0.35);

    UOld=U;
    VOld=V;

    UU=U;
    VV=V;


    for i=1:NTS

        UU(2:NAS-1) = ((b(2:NAS-1) .* UU(1:NAS-2) + a(2:NAS-1) .* UOld(2:NAS-1) + c(2:NAS-1) .* UOld(3:NAS)) ./ gamma(2:NAS-1));
        VY(NAS-1:-1:2) = ((b(NAS-1:-1:2) .* VOld(NAS-2:-1:1) + a(NAS-1:-1:2) .* VOld(NAS-1:-1:2) + c(NAS-1:-1:2) .* VV(NAS:-1:3)) ./ gamma(NAS-1:-1:2));



        for j = 2:NAS-1
            U(j) = (b(j) * U(j-1) + a(j) * UOld(j) + c(j) * UOld(j+1)) / gamma(j);
            V(NAS-j+1) = (b(NAS-j+1) * VOld(NAS-j+1-1) + a(NAS-j+1) * VOld(NAS-j+1) + c(NAS-j+1) * V(NAS-j+1+1)) / gamma(NAS-j+1);
        end


        display(sum(U(2:NAS-1)'-UU(2:NAS-1)'));
        display(sum(V(2:NAS-1)'-VV(2:NAS-1)'));

    end

    display([U' UU']);
    display([V' VV']);
```

Comment: Is `gamma` MATLAB's built-in function or your own variable here?

Comment: my own variable

Comment: Then rename it and check if you get the right result. MATLAB might be calling its built-in `gamma` function.

Comment: I did and still not working , I tried this also but still don't match the results

U(2:NAS-1)= arrayfun(@(j)(((b(j) * U(j-1) + a(j)* UOld(j) + c(j) * UOld(j+1)) / Gamma(j))), 2:NAS-1)

Comment: For me your code works perfectly fine, but certainly with randomly filled data. It would be useful to see what are dimensions of the matrices you are using.

Comment: as simples as (1xn)

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with the result you get?

Comment: Please, post a [mcve]

Comment: Just did as requested, thank you